# Show that $\int_\mathbb{R} f' g = - \int_\mathbb{R} f g'$ for $f, g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f, g, f', g' \in L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Say we have  $f, g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f, g, f', g' \in L^2$. I want to show that $\int_\mathbb{R} f' g = - \int_\mathbb{R} f g'$.

I see that
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R} (fg)' d\lambda = \int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot (fg(x + 1/n) - fg(x)) d\lambda(x)
\end{equation}
so I wanted to show that:
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot (fg(x + 1/n) - fg(x)) d\lambda(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\mathbb{R} n \cdot (fg(x + 1/n) - fg(x)) d\lambda(x) = 0
\end{equation}
However, I don't see how I could prove this convergence. The function $n (fg(x + 1/n) - fg(x))$ doesn't seem to be bounded by some integrable function, so I cannot use the dominated convergence. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Use integration by parts and show that, given your assumptions, the border term vanishes

Comment: So you mean something like $\int f'g = fg - \int fg'$? But why must $fg(x)$ vanish for large $x$? What if we take $f, g$ to be $C^1$-approximation of $h$ where $h(x) = 1$ on $x \in [n, n + 1/(n^2)], n \in {2, 3, ...}$ and $h(x) = 0$ otherwise? This is in $L^2$ and can certainly be made into $C^1$ function, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, this example doesn't work because $f'$ is not in $L^1$ in this case. Still, how do you prove that the border term vanishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use integration by parts.

The boundary term vanishes because of the control on the functions **and** the derivatives:

$$(f g)'(x) = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) g'(x),$$

so $(fg)'$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ as the sum of products of $L^2$-functions. It follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (fg)(x) = f(0)g(0)+\int_0^\infty (fg)'(t)\,\mathrm dt$ exists, and thus, since $fg\in L^1$, the limit must be equal to $0$.

Similarly (left to you), $\lim_{x\to-\infty} (fg)(x)=0$.

Comment: why does $f(0)g(0) + \int_0^\infty (fg)'(t) dt = 0$?

Comment: @AbbyJean It is the limit of $fg(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ (the limit exists because $(fg)'\in L^1$), and any $L^1(\mathbb R)$ function that converges as $x\to\infty$ must converge to $0$.